# Opening Hyperlink from WPF RichTextBox via Touch

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some hyperlinks in my WPF RichTextBox that works perfectly when I click them (as in, they do open). However, when I touch them via my touchscreen monitor, they don't open. It seems that the touch events are not downgraded to click events.

When I touch them, the links become bold in font. The effect is the same as when I hover my mouse over them.

Any idea how do I open them via touch?

Comment: And after a second click, do they work?

Comment: Usually, you should use a Command to make sure the link is opened. If you want to keep it event-based, you might want to try out the specific Touch events for touch input.

Comment: @KamilSolecki no they don't, no matter how many times I press the screen

Comment: @Akku how do I use a command to make sure the link is opened? For event base, you mean something like detecting the touch down event and sending a mouse click event to the respective location?

Comment: No, with event-based I mean that you use methods for certain events where you do what you want to do. If you set a Command in the UI controls command property, the control usually redirects all usual events so that they trigger the Command. If you want to know how to create a command, Google for DelegateCommand.